# Require at most one instance of component on a page

Tags: adobe, components, instance, aem, day-cq

I develop the site with Day CQ5. I am developing templates, components, and pages and faced with a problem. On the page of the site can be one instance of component, and need to prevent the addition of other instances. How can I do this? Maybe someone has faced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authors don't need the ability to add the component to different areas (parsys containers) of the page, you could just include it in a static location. Authors could then either populate the component or leave it blank to hide it. Then you would leave it out of the sidekick so they couldn't add additional copies.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you have to offer include a component directly to a page that is used a template?

Comment: With this approach loses flexibility. The component will be bound to a concrete place on the page, and I can not put anything else there.

Comment: Yes, it does reduce the flexibility (but it sounds like that's what you're trying to do). You could allow other components in the same section as your static component by placing parsys components above and/or below the component you're trying to restrict.

Comment: I use this method because I can not find a better solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint, but it might solve your problem: http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/Development/Components/HowToDefineComponentListDynamically.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as I understand, it says that the list of available components is handled on the client side. Maybe worth a try to write a listener for parsis. He will check the availability of a component on the page, and if such a component is already there, the script will prevent the adding. While I do not really imagine how it should work:(

Comment: Actually it's sad, what this case not be handled using standard tools of CMS.